# Browserify with nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am creating a sample application to learn how to use nodejs for client side. I have installed : node, npm with browserify before running this exercise;

Directory Structure

```
lesseon1
 - index.html
 - application.js
 - js
   - data.js
   - listdata.js
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Lesson 1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="names"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ol = document.createElement("ol");
        ol.innerHTML = window.list;
        document.getElementById("names").appendChild(ol);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**listdata.js**

```
var jsonData = require("./data.js");

for(item in jsonData){
    console.log(jsonData[item].name);
    window.list += "<li>" + jsonData[item].name + "</li>";
}

console.log(window.list);
```

**data.js**

```
var json = [{
    "name" : "Rohit"
    },{
    "name" : "Amit"
    },{
    "name" : "Arti"
    }];
```

And application.js is being generated using browerify

```
~/node_modules/.bin/browserify -e js/listdata.js -o application.js
```

**Problem :**

It is printing undefined in browser and browser console too. However if I copy paste js code in index.html, everything works fine.
In listdata.js, there are 2 console.log() statements. But it is executing only last one.

Am I missing something? or doing something in wrong way.

Comment: `require` in JS doesn't work the same way as `require` in PHP; you should export something from a module. Put `module.exports = json;` in your `data.js` file and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not export from `data.js`.

```
var json = [{
    "name" : "Rohit"
    },{
    "name" : "Amit"
    },{
    "name" : "Arti"
    }];
module.exports = json;
```

Or you can change to `data.json` and just type in valid json without `var` or `exports` and use it in `listdata.js` as `var jsonData = require("./data.json");`

Each `require`d file, `browserify` [wraps into function](http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/) with `function (require, module, exports)` signature. That is reason why you might not have some variables globally. If you want so, use `global.` or `window.`.

Comment: Ahhh .. how I missed it .